# How to make buttons go on the same level

Tags: html, css

how do I make it so i have 2 columns of buttons, on the same level?

so i have 4 buttons on the left side, and 2 on the right. Right now the right ones are under the left ones (but still on the right), but I want them to be on the same level.

[so this is what my code looks like rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnbQQ.png)
[i want it to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NURZx.png)

Code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

div.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button,
button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    white-space: wrap;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover,
.button:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #888;
    outline: 0;
}

.button_social,
button_social {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 1150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    white-space: wrap;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button_social:hover,
.button_social:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #888;
    outline: 0;
}

.button_discord,
button_discord {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 350px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    white-space: wrap;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button_discord:hover,
.button_discord:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #888;
    outline: 0;
}

.button.button-primary {
    color: #FFF;
    filter: brightness(90%)
}

.icon {
    padding: 0px 8px 3.5px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.button_social.button-discord {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #5865F2
}

.button_social.button-discord:hover,
.button_social.button-discord:focus {
    filter: brightness(90%)
}


/* Github */
.button_social.button-github {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000
}

.button_social.button-github:hover,
.button_social.button-github:focus {
    filter: brightness(90%)
}

/* Twitch */
.button_social.button-twitch {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #9146ff
}

.button_social.button-twitch:hover,
.button_social.button-twitch:focus {
    filter: brightness(90%)
}

/* YouTube */
.button_social.button-youtube {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000
}

.button_social.button-youtube:hover,
.button_social.button-youtube:focus {
    filter: brightness(90%)
}
```

Comment: deppending how your HTML is, but you didn't show it...

Comment: some css errors, like `button_social` doesn't exist in HML... read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mister Jojo already has stated it's a bit tricky to help you all the way with just the CSS, but a few solutions that I think would help are:

- Making a grid for your buttons [MDN Docs for CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
- Displaying the buttons with flex (mabey in `flex-direction: column;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;` to allow wrapping to the next column) [MDN Docs for CSS Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)
- A HTML structure where they are in separate containers (divs?) that are half the width of your desired area and are set to `display: inline-block`

Any of these would probably do the trick but without your HTML it's hard to say what solution would fit you best

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap those buttons inside a `<div>` for example. Than those two divs should be placed one next to other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **flexbox**. Your container should include `display: flex`. You can justify and align your items. [Here is more about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Use grid/ flex system.

You can also try to use tailwind.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

button {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

.btn-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-wrap">
            <button>github</button>
            <button>discord</button>
            <button>twitch</button>
            <button>youtube</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-wrap">
            <button>chattotwitch discord bot</button>
            <button>lightning discord bot</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```